# order of mock objects while using patch in unittests

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

```
@patch('module1.api.method1')  
@patch('module1.api.method2')
class TestApi(unittest.TestCase):

        @patch('module1.api.connec1')    
        @patch('module1.api.connec2')  
        def test_some_method(self, mockMethod1, mockMethod2, 
                                mockConnec1, mockConnec2):
            # some code.....
```

Does the order of mock objects mentioned in the test method should be the same as `patch`? Do we need to mention mock objects for all class level and method level patches?

Will approach be the same if there are like 20 patch objects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the patch docs:

> When you nest patch decorators the mocks are passed in to the
>   decorated function in the same order they applied (the normal Python
>   order that decorators are applied). This means from the bottom up

So the correct order in your code would be:

```
@patch('module1.api.method1')  
@patch('module1.api.method2')
class TestApi(unittest.TestCase):

        @patch('module1.api.connec1')    
        @patch('module1.api.connec2')  
        def test_some_method(self, mockConnec2, mockConnec1, mockMethod2, mockMethod1):
         # some code.....
```

If you have lots of these kinds of mocks & you don't need to do anything (like defining side_effect etc.) in each of them, you can roll them up with `*args` for brevity.